# datagrip seems to use deprecated version of clickhouse jdbc driver

Tags: jdbc, clickhouse, datagrip

In datagrip when you select a driver for clickhouse you can only select the old deprecated (ru.yandex) driver. I cannot figure out how to use the latest (com.clickhouse) driver.

Maven groupId ru.yandex.clickhouse and legacy JDBC driver ru.yandex.clickhouse.ClickHouseDriver are deprecated.

Please use new groupId com.clickhouse and driver com.clickhouse.jdbc.ClickHouseDriver instead. It's highly recommended to upgrade to 0.3.2+ and start to integrate the new JDBC driver for improved performance and stability.

Comment: As a temporary workaround, please, upload and use [the latest JDBC driver version](https://github.com/ClickHouse/clickhouse-jdbc/releases/tag/v0.3.2-patch6)

Comment: thank you, that workaround did the trick.

Comment: Update withing DataGrip is delayed due to [JDBC driver issue](https://github.com/ClickHouse/clickhouse-jdbc/issues/871).  Put `+1` on [GitHub issue for promotion](https://github.com/ClickHouse/clickhouse-jdbc/issues/871)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the report. We in DataGrip will fix that.